# I am trying to pass the id of a user from the users table from an authenticated users profile

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to pass the id of a user from the users table from an authenticated users profile in a chat application I am trying to build. I keep getting SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'recever' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `chats` (`message`, `sender`, `recever`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (hi, 2, ?, 2021-05-24 21:13:20, 2021-05-24 21:13:20)). The recever column is always empty because I couldn't pass the id value of the user.

My Controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Chat;
use App\Models\typing;
use App\Models\User;
use Auth;
use DB;
use URL;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class ChatController extends Controller
{
    
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function store(Request $request, $id=null){
        $auth_id = Auth::user()->id;
        
        $user = DB::table('users')->where('id', $id)->first();

        $chat = new Chat;
        $chat->message = $request->message;
        $chat->sender = $auth_id;
        $chat->recever = $user->id;
        $chat->save();
        typing::where('recever',$chat->recever)
              ->where('sender', $chat->sender)
              ->update(['check_status' => 0]);
        return back();
    }
}
```

My Blade file

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<?php
$recever=Route::input('id');    
$id=Auth::id();
$user = DB::table('users')->where('id', $recever)->first();
?>
<link href="{{ asset('css/style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
            
                <div class="panel-heading" style="height:40px;">
                  <div class="pull-left">
                  <a onclick="seenUpdate()" style="color:#fff;text-decoration:none; margin-left: 12px;" href="{{URL::to('/')}}"> 
                     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"> 
                     
                     
                     </span> <b class="smsnum"id="smsnum"></b> Message
                </a>
               
               
                <a style="color:#fff;text-decoration:none; margin-left: 12px;" href="{{URL::to('/users')}}"> 
                     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> User
                </a>
                </a>
                <a style="color:#fff; text-decoration:none;    margin-left: 12px;" href="{{URL::to('/')}}"> 
                     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Search 
                </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="pull-right"> 
                        {{$user->name}}
                    </div>
                </div>
            

                <div class="panel-body" id="scrolltoheight">
                <ul class="chat">
                       <div id="chat-message"> 
                       </div>

                </ul>
                
                </div>
               <div class="typing"><p id="typing"></p></div> 
                <div class="panel-footer">
                <form id="message-submit" action="{{ url('/send-message/'.$user->id) }}" method="post"> {{ csrf_field()}}

                   <div class="input-group">             
                        <input onkeyup="typing()" id="message" type="text" name="message" required class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Type your message here..." />
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" id="btn-chat"value="Send"/>                              
                        </span>
                    </div>
              
                
                </form>
                  
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@endsection
```

My Home controller that holds the home.blade.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Chat;
use DB;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable
     */
    public function index()
    {
        
        return view('home');
    }

    public function allmessage()
    { 
        return view('allmessage');
    }
    function jsonResponse(){
        $user = DB::table('chats')->get();
        return response()->json($user);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `dd($auth_id)` and `dd($user)` to see if they are already `null`

Comment: Are you aware of your typo? "recever" has to be "receiver"

Comment: It is not a typo, I did that on purpose

Comment: Okay, then it's a "spelling error on purpose" ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Probably either `$auth_id` or `$user` is null as assumed above

Comment: <form id="message-submit" action="{{ url('/send-message'/$user->id) }}" this is incorrect. it should be `{{ url('/send-message/'.$user->id) }}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to pass all of the model, instead you should pass only the id, try this:

```
//$chat->recever = $user;
$chat->recever = $user->id;
```

Also in your blade change this:

```
<form id="message-submit" action="{{ url('/send-message') }}" method="post">
```

To this:

```
<form id="message-submit" action="{{ url('/send-message/'.$user->id) }}" method="post">
```

The reason for this change is you are not passing the user of id, so it returns as null.

Comment: After implementing this, I got this error "Trying to get property 'id' of non-object"

Comment: @FiyinfoluwaOsuntola I updated my answer, if it does not work share your route (ex: web.php)

Comment: I have updated my codes as suggested and also updated my routes in my web.php file to `Route::post('/send-message/{id}','ChatController@store');` But a new problem of Trying to get property 'id' of non-object (View: C:\wamp64\www\chat\resources\views\home.blade.php) in my blade file shows up at this line `<form id="message-submit" action="{{ url('/send-message/'.$user->id) }}" method="post"> {{ csrf_field()}}`

Comment: @FiyinfoluwaOsuntola On which line? Can you also update your question with current codes?

Comment: I have updated my codes. Check the new controller I uploaded and also the home.blade.php file. Line 48